# Does the Google Drive Android API work for all Google accounts?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I’m trying to save some user preferences across multiple devices on my Android application.

Do I need to request the user other authentication credentials or additional steps to enable the Google Drive Android API beside the Google account they already have?

Is Google Drive available for all Google accounts?

Comment: It will depend on your implementation, you may choose to authenticate per user or use a domain-wide delegation. For a normal authorization process, it will be per user ([single user flow](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/05/improving-security-and-user-experience.html)). Making a request for a user may require their credentials and permission. For a domain wide-delegation, [Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#perform_g_suite_domain-wide_delegation_of_authority) on programmatically accessing users data without any manual authorization on their part

Comment: @Mr.Rebot I was able to save/read a file in the App folder (single user flow). It requires the user to pick an account (even when she is already logged in), and then enable access to Google Drive. That’s a terrible UX, I think. Do I need to host the G Suite in my domain for my app to have domain-wide delegation of authority? I forgot to mention that my app is a game, maybe I would be better off using the [Google Play Games Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames), what do you think?