# How to verify user purchased premium version using in app product in android?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have developed an app in which I want to give a premium version of an app with ad removal and some extra features in-app products.

So, my question is how to verify if a user had purchased already; Then, when a user opens the app, I know if I should give them a premium interface.

Comment: Acces his google account and write it in his account? [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894531/syncing-app-data-to-google-account)

Comment: i am thinking about using firebase with google login and real time database with fields email, premium_enable - true/false (with additional shared preference for offline) will be any problem there?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html) overview for In App Billing, where it says:

> Google Play tracks and manages the ownership information of managed products. When a user purchases a managed product, Google Play stores the purchase information for each product on a per-user basis. This enables you to later query Google Play at any time to restore the state of the products a specific user has purchased. This information is persistent on the Google Play servers even if the user uninstalls the application or if they change devices.

To provide premium content, you'll need to create a managed product that doesn't get consumed in the app when the user purchases it. In order to query the user's in-app purchases, send a [getPurchases()](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getPurchases) request, that will return all the current un-consumed products owned by the user.

If  you find the premium content in this response, you know the user has purchased it and can grant them the premium interface.

Comment: How do you advise handling times when the user is offline? The user wants rightly access to his purchased content, but a fraudulent user could easily fake validity while offline

Comment: AIDL is now deprecated. Please refer [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/06/advanced-in-app-billing-handling.html) for updates or my direct answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Google Play Billing AIDL](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html) is now deprecated and will be removed in a future release. To implement Google Play Billing features, use [the Google Play Billing library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview) and to get purchases details for all the items bought within your app use: [queryPurchases(skuType)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#querypurchases).